# Launcher.LaunchFileAsync fails for opening a file extension associated with a desktop app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, desktop-application, winrt-async

I am trying using file association to open a desktop app from modern app. I followed all the steps correctly and am able to open the .try files with updater.exe through windows explorer. But when I try to do the same thing in my modern app programmatically, using

```
bool success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

I am getting the return value as false all the time. This works if I use DisplayApplicationPicker. What is going wrong here?

Comment: the documentation states 
"The calling app must be visible to the user when the API is invoked.

This API also imposes several restrictions on what types of files it can launch. Many file types that contain executable code, for example .exe, .msi, and .js files, are blocked from launching."

Maybe one of these conditions are to fault? (otherwise, you should best update your question accordingly)

Comment: The files are simple 0 byte .try files(custom extension). We are trying to open it so that we can invoke updater.exe from our modern app. I read the same text on MSDN about exe files but these are not exes. Also, why does it launch with the DisplayApplicationPicker and not without it?

Comment: I am having this issue as well. It is obviously bug. It only works when debugging on local machine. Simulator and tablet doesnt work for me. If you set DisplayApplicationPicker, it works ok. Have you solved this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This is a know bug and there is no way for this to work if the user did not choose your app as least once. If you need inter-app communication, you can use "protocol association" which works every time.

Regards.